# Языкознание и языковедение — есть ли разница?

Tags: синонимы

Есть ли у данных слов смысловые отличия? Или же это редкий случай полной синонимии? Можно ли их разнести (одно, например, определить для теоретической стороны, а другое — для прикладной) и как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

В книгах по лексикологии эти слова относят к абсолютным(полным) синонимам. Сюда же относится и лингвистика( более позднее слово). Однако и они частично отличаются прежде всего сочетаемостью и словообразовательными возможностями. Названия новых направлений науки о языке включают в себя слово **лингвистика — математическая, структурная, компьютерная, социолингвистика, психолингвистика, онтолингвистика; широко употребляются производные слова — лингвист, лингвистический.** Наличие производных удерживает в синонимическом ряду я**зыковедение — языковед, языковедческий, но на фоне доминанты ряда оно звучит как архаизм.**

Answer (score 2):

Из словаря

ЯЗЫКОЗНАНИЕ,  1. **Наука о языке**, об общих законах существования и исторического развития человеческого языка; лингвистика. Сравнительно-историческое я. 2. **Учебный предмет**, изучающий эту науку. Преподавать я.

ЯЗЫКОВЕДЕНИЕ,  =Языкознание (1 зн.).

Возможно, раньше слово "языковедение" применялось чаще, вот пример: "Там студенты занимались по первому изданию учебника Реформатского 1947 года. Он назывался «Введение **в языковедение**». Этой книге была уготована прекрасная судьба".

Для названия современных учебников и научных дисциплин в основном используется  **термин "языкознание"** (языковедение, как мне кажется,  вытесняется на второй план, приобретает архаичный оттенок):

(1)Можно, по-видимому, сказать, что сегодня сравнительно-историческое языкознание ― самая точная из гуманитарных наук.

(2) История русского языка и общее языкознание: Избр. работы.

Answer (score 1):

Лингвистика конечно хорошо, но только иностранных слов и так уж слишком много стало.. особенно в последнее время. Потому лучше слова свои сохранять, насколько это возможно, конечно же.

Несмотря на то, что многие, если не все, считают, что слова "знать" и "ведать" синонимы, мне видится -- на каком-то тонком.. интуитивном, так сказать, уровне -- что это не совсем так. **Знамо** и **ведомо** не совсем одно и то же. Первое заключает в себе более общее, поверхностное значение, информацию; тогда как последнее означает то, что можно назвать "глубинным знанием", саму суть, которую несёт в себе та или иная информация. Это как "осознание" и "понимание" как бы синонимы и в то же время одно "охватывает", а другое "вмещает". Не умею лучше объяснить.. пока.

А вот отрывок из книги Мартена Феллера  "Как рождаются и живут слова" \1964г.\ , глава "О детализации, которая теряет смысл."   Не обезсудьте, если объём покажется вам через чур большим.

" ...исчезновение различий между глаголами *знать* и *ведать* привело к смерти одного из них.

Русское слово *знать* можно перевести на немецкий двумя словами: *kennen* и *wissen*. Во французском языке также два слова могут служить для перевода нашего *знать*. Почему же в других языках два слова, а у нас одно?

Но всегда ли было у нас так? Действительно, сегодня слово *знать* обозначает в нашем языке с одной стороны, „иметь о чем-то сведения, понятие”, „разбираться в чем-то", а с другой стороны, „быть знакомым”.

Рассмотрим другие слова. Может быть, они нам помогут ответить на поставленный вопрос.

У нас есть слова *естествознание* (наука о природе) и *естествоведение*, обозначающие почти одно и то же; есть слова ***языкознание*** и ***языковедение***. Что это за *ведение*, что это за корень **вед**?

Корень **вед** очень древний, общий многим индоевропейским языкам. Он обозначал знания, мудрость. Священная книга древних народов Индии, написанная на санскрите, носит название „Веды", что значит „знание". У нас еще в прошлом веке писали *ведаю* наряду со *знаю*, и сейчас можно встретить фразу *не ведает, что творит*, т. е. не знает, что делает. [скорее "не понимает"; прим.- ирш]

От корня **вед** у нас немало слов: *сведения, ведомости*. Сейчас *ведомости* обычно отчетные, а во времена Петра I это было название газеты. Заголовок первой русской газеты, вышедшей в 1703 г., так и гласил: „Ведомости". И все же в русском языке сам корень **вед** увял, был вытеснен корнем **зна**. Глагол от корня **вед** приобрел новое значение —„ведать чем-то", т. е. чем-то управлять.

Но если корень **зна** вытеснил корень **вед** потому, что стал означать совершенно то же самое, вероятно, когда-то эти корни обозначалн нечто различное.

Присмотримся, как переводится на немецкий язык наше слово *знать*. *Я знаю математику.* Здесь мы при переводе употребим глагол *wissen*. Я знаю этого человека. На этот раз придется использовать слово *kennen*. Подобным же образом *знать* — „иметь сведения", „понимать" — мы переведем на французский глаголом *sauoir*, а *знать* — „быть знакомым" — с помощью глагола *connaître*. Правда, такое условие и у французов, и у немцев выдерживается теперь не очень четко, но это потому, что значения обоих глаголов сближаются, начинают смешиваться и, может быть, через какое-то время один из них исчезнет, а второй будет заменять его во всех случаях, как это произошло в нашем языке или у англичан.

В английском языке тоже остались только следы корня—родича нашего **вед**: в словах *wise* — мудрый, *wisdom* — мудрость.

Но вернемся к нашему разговору.

Можем ли мы теперь определить, что значили когда-то корни **вед** и **зна**? Вероятно, **вед** указывал на что-то вроде научного познания, а **зна**?..

В древности люди наносили на свое тело татуировку. Эта татуировка была знаком, указывающим на принадлежность людей к роду; по знакам узнавали, свой человек или чужой, родич или не родич. Слово *знак* образовано от корня **зна**, обозначавшего „быть родственным", „единокровным”.

Мы теперь говорим о наших лучших рабочих и крестьянах — *знатные* люди и думаем обычно, что *знатные* означает, что их все знают. Это сегодняшнее содержание слова. А когда-то знатными называли князей, графов и не потому, что их все знали, а потому, что они были родовитые. Чем стариннее был род, тем представитель его был более знатным. *Знать, узнавать* первоначально означало „определять принадлежность к роду".

Немецкое *kennen* — „быть знакомым", „знать" — того же индоевропейского корня, что и латинское *genere* — рождать. А в латинском *cognosco*, от которого французское слово *connaître* —„знать", мы вновь находим тот же корень, что и в *genere*. Да и наше *знать*, видимо, в родстве с ними.

Одни знания люди приобретали путем специального изучения — это обозначалось словами от корня **вед**; знания, приходившие как бы сами собой, такие, как знание родичей, обозначались корнем **зна**. Постепенно это разделение потеряло смысл.

Вот почему во многих языках пока еще есть два слова, обозначающие то, что мы теперь обозначаем одним нашим *знать*. И у нас второе слово уже не употребляется, так как нет отдельного второго понятия."